# Is an NSInvocationOperation generated operation complete when its selector finishes?

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue, nsinvocationoperation

If I create an `NSOperation` via `NSInvocationOperation`, does completion of the chosen selector cause the `NSOperation` to complete and be removed from the operation queue?

For example:

```
...
NSDictionary* params = @{KEY_SERVER_ID:serverId, KEY_USERNAME:username, KEY_PASSWORD:password};
NSInvocationOperation* op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(publishBulletinBoardRead:) object:params];
[[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperation:op];
...
```

When `publishBulletinBoardRead:` returns, can I assume that the operation is removed from the queue?